# Deriving value of T

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The following shows a dynamic equation for the thermal behavior in zone *i*. The rate of temperature change $\dot{T}$ (over period of *t*) of zone *i* is affected by the thermal resistances *R* and capacitance *C* of its adjacent zones *o*, *j*, *k*, *l*, and other features *Q* and the change of *H*.

$$ \dot{T}_i= \frac{- [ \frac{1}{R_{i,o}} + \frac{1}{R_{i,j}} + \frac{1}{R_{i,k}} + \frac{1}{R_{i,l}} ] T_i +  \frac{T_{i,o}}{R_{i,o}} + \frac{T_{i,j}}{R_{i,j}} + \frac{T_{i,k}}{R_{i,k}} + \frac{T_{i,l}}{R_{i,l}} + Q_i^p + ∆H_i}{C_i}$$

$$∆H_i= m_i^{in} (1.006 T_i^{in}+W_i^{in} (2501 + 1.84 T_i^{in})) - m_i^{out} (1.006 T_i^i+W_i^i (2501 + 1.84 T_i^i)) $$

My question is, given this formula, how can I derive the value of $T_i$? Is it an integral of $\dot{T}$? Some very fundamental calculus and keyword indication will be very much helpful. Thanks!

$$T_i = ?? $$

Comment: What is the meaning of double subscript index variables $T_{i,k}$? are they simply constants?

Comment: Yes. They are measured inputs. Let say, 22 Celcius for all double subscript index variables $T_{i,o}$, $T_{i,j}$, $T_{i,k}$, $T_{i,l}$

Comment: You may also assume $R_{i,o}$ and all remaining double subscript index variables of *R* equal to 0.5. *Q* equals 100. Assume all variables are given except $T_i$

Answer (score 1):

Well, your equation is simply a first order differential equation. What you need to do is to simply gather all the terms, and obtain the following form
$$
\dot{T}_i+\alpha  T_i=\beta
$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ are **constant**, namely, independent of $T_i$.

Then, you can read in any book on this topic how to solve this simple equation. Particularly, it can be shown that the solution is given by
$$
T_i(t) = \frac{\beta}{\alpha}+ C\cdot e^{-\alpha t}
$$
where $C$ is to be determined from the initial constraints you have on $T_i$. *For example*, the constraint $T_i(0)=0$ would mean that $0= \frac{\beta}{\alpha}+ C$, and thus $C=-\beta/\alpha$.

Note that you can substitute this solution in the above differential equation and see its correctness.